# Invalid character error while parsing xml in php

Tags: xml, parsing

<meta_description><![CDATA[Its a frightening sign of these tough economic times: Each Spirit Halloween store in the Bay Area has gotten close to a thousand applications for the 25 to 40 jobs it will have available this year.]]></meta_description>

Hi guys,

I am not able to parse above xml as its giving invalid character error. I am using xml_parser_create of PHP

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Umesh Kulkarni.