# Understand xml parsing in Apple sample code

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

I'm studying Apple's [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code. I'd like to understand how the app is pulling data from the RSS feed included in the app:
    http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/toppaidapplications/limit=75/xml

**How are the contents at the above url parsed?** Viewing the page source reveals HTML with no apparent xml section. While looking through the sample parsing code I found a few symbols like `im:name`. However these symbols are not in the contents of the above url.

I tried to host the contents of the above url locally (w/ limit=1). However pointing the sample code to `@"~/Desktop/a.xml"` causes the application to throw the error `unsupported url`.

**More info**: While reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rss I came across what I expected to see at phobos link above. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
        <title>RSS Title</title>
        <description>This is an example of an RSS feed</description>
        <link>http://www.someexamplerssdomain.com/main.html</link>
        <pubDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2009 16:45:00 +0000 </pubDate>

        <item>
                <title>Example entry</title>
                <description>an interesting description</description>
                <link>http://www.wikipedia.org/</link>
                <guid>unique string per item</guid>
                <pubDate>Mon, 06 Sep 2009 16:45:00 +0000 </pubDate>
        </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

**Is there an equivalent "human-readable" xml document corresponding to the above phobos link somewhere?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the feed you're looking at technically isn't an RSS Feed.  It's an [Atom 1.0](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fphobos.apple.com%2FWebObjects%2FMZStoreServices.woa%2Fws%2FRSS%2Ftoppaidapplications%2Flimit%3D75%2Fxmlhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499188/invalid-character-error-while-parsing-xml-in-phphttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499188/invalid-character-error-while-parsing-xml-in-php) Feed, but both are popular XML-based feed formats.

If you view the source of the feed you will see the XML elements you're looking for, like:

```
<entry>
  <updated>2011-12-09T16:15:32-07:00</updated>
  <id>http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tetris/id479943969?mt=8&amp;uo=2</id>
  <title>TETRIS® - Electronic Arts</title>
  <summary>Long summary here</summary>
  <im:name>TETRIS®</im:name>
  ...
</entry>
```

Some browser versions parse RSS/Atom feeds into user-friendly HTML pages and present them instead of the actual feed, it sounds like that's the type of HTML page you're viewing.

On a OS X, you could use a command like Curl to download the feed in a Terminal:

```
curl -o feed.xml http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/toppaidapplications/limit=75/xml
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'd like to host the feed myself. Then modify the contents of the feed. How does one host an Atom 1.0 formatted feed?